Purpose of barrel grip jig saw design
What is the intended purpose of the barrel grip jig saw design?

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/bosch-variable-speed-barrel-grip-jig-saw/1000166473

Is there a benefit compared to the traditional top-handle design?

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/bosch-120v-corded-top-handle-jig-saw-with-variable-speed-toolless-blade-change-system-and-carrying-case/1000676943

I find the barrel grip provide a little bit more control on curves and straightness of the cut (hand higher up makes it more easy to lever it out of 90 degrees if you have one that doesn't lock the sled). The downside with the barrel styles I've seen are that there is no variable speed via a trigger.
That said, my recommendation is to buy one that feels good in your hand. Both do the job just fine.

Thanks. It's been a long time since I've used a jigsaw. I remember hating them as a kid; I found them clumsy. Do you have any tips for finding a jigsaw that is especially smooth and pleasant to operate? For cutting plywood. And I've even been told a jigsaw can be used to cut mild steel sheets up to 3/16" thick. Although I imagine that's pushing the limits.

@User1974 It's not so much about the saw as it is the blades you use. Get good quality blades designed to make the cut you are wanting to make. Higher teeth per inch (TPI) results a cleaner cut, but it is slower.

I agree--it's more difficult to apply forward pressure from up high since the tool wants to tilt. That said, I almost never use my jigsaw. It's not a precision tool in many cases.

I’d say try both — don’t just hold them. (Fwiw, I sold off a barrel grip because I just didn’t get on with it. Everybody has different preferences.)

The top one will let you get a better grip on the front of the saw with your weak hand.  It will also place your dominant hand closer to the surface to be cut, which gives you better control (imagine if the saw was 3 ft tall how hard it would be to control).
